# Consistent replica selection approach for a dynamic list

Tags: algorithm

I have a dynamic (changing over time) optional list. Each input is a key(string), and I need to select a item from the list according to the key. Since the optional list is constantly changing, I know that 100% consistency rate is difficult to achieve. Is there any good way to have the highest possible consistency rate for a dynamic list?

Add an example to make it more clear:

(1) 1st time, the dynamic list is [item1, item2, item3, item4].

Key is 'abc'. Let's assume the chosen item is 'item2'

Key is '123'. Let's assume the chosen item is 'item3'

(2) 2nd time, the dynamic list becomes [item2, item3, item4].

Key is 'abc'. I hope the chosen item is still 'item2'

Key is '123'. I hope the chosen item is still 'item3'

(3) 3rd time, the dynamic list becomes [item0, item1, item2, item3, item4].

Key is 'abc'. I hope the chosen item is still 'item2'

Key is '123'. I hope the chosen item is still 'item3'

(4) 4th time, the dynamic list becomes [item0, item1, item3, item4].

Key is 'abc'. Since 'item2' is not in the list any more, it's ok to choose another item from the list.

Key is '123'. I hope the chosen item is still 'item3'

**Note: The consistency rate does not need to be 100%. Any value of Key is possible and I hope it won't take up too much memory. So a hash table to record every key-item pair is not considered.**

Comment: You should look for the Caching approach. For high # of requests, it is really efficient. Also, for high availability and consistency, you should prefer a distributed database, e.g., DynamoDB/Cassandra. If you don't wanna use a full fledged database separately, use any Caching library (e.g. memcached), or our good old Redis.

Comment: *"optional list"*: do you mean you need to register whether a key is present in the list or not? *"select a item"*: you mean items are identified by key? Then surely a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) is the way to go.

Comment: @trincot thanks for your reply. Hash table takes up too much memory and it’s out of our consideration. We don't need the consistency rate to be 100%. The main problem here is how to improve the consistency as much as possible in a dynamic situation and not spend too much memory.

Comment: What is the average/maximum memory footprint of the list and what are the memory constraints? I'm surprised that you don't have a memory problem for the items but claim that storing them in a hashtable poses a memory problem. Are we talking about Terrabytes?

Comment: @trincot the max number of item list won't be larger than 1000 in our scenario. But the key is set by the client and we don't know the scope of its value. If we use the hash table directly, the cost of the memory will mainly be recorded on the various hash values ​​of the key.

Comment: @trincot In fact, we currently do this: take the hash value of each item in the list. Hash the key, and return the item corresponding to the value closest to the hash value of the key through binary search. The memory cost of this method is very small, and the consistency is very good if the item list remains unchanged. The problem is that this item list is dynamic, which brings inconsistency. So I'm thinking about the direction of optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Every possible 2 character string using letters A,B, and C to store 3 items.

```
"AA" = Item 2.
"AB" =
"AC" =
"BA" = Item 1.
"BB" =
"BC" =
"CA" =
"CB" = Item 3.
"CC" =
```

But it is not necessary to store all 9 possible strings. Only 3 key,value pairs need to be stored.

```
"AA" = Item 2.
"BA" = Item 1.
"CB" = Item 3.
```

[Edited]

To make this work you need 4 subroutines. The first subroutine finds the index for a particular key. The second subroutine returns the value for a particular key. The third subroutine adds an item to the changing list. The fourth subroutine removes an item from the list. Here is pseudocode for the four subroutines.

```
Array key[];
Array value[];

int GetIndexForKey(keyStr)
{ //----Find index corresponding to keyStr using binary search.
  ...
  return index;
}

object GetValueForKey(keyStr)
{ ind = GetIndexForKey(keyStr);
  return value[ind];
}

void AddValueForKey(keyStr, val)
{ ind = GetIndexForKey(keyStr);
  if (ind != NULL) //----keyStr already exists.
  { value[ind]=val; //----Change value.
  }
  else
  { //----Add key and value to ordered arrays.
    ...
    //----Sort list.
    ...
  }
}

void DeleteKey(keyStr)
{ //----Remove key,value pair from ordered list.
  ...
}
```

If you don't have any control of what or when something is changed in the dynamic list, you might be able to 1. occasionally ask the dynamic list questions. or 2. register for notification of changes.

For the first case, you could have a process loop trying to keep the replica as consistent as possible. The dynamic list might have a way to keep a count of the number of changes.

For the second case, as soon as a change occurs, you would receive a notification and could change your replica.

Answer (score 0):

You could do [rendezvous hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendezvous_hashing). The Python implementation below is slow since it uses a (presumed) PRF out of general paranoia, but depending on your goals, you could use a fast fingerprint function like CityHash instead.

```py
import hmac
import secrets
import struct


def encode_pair(key, option):
    key = key.encode()
    option = option.encode()
    return b"".join([struct.pack("<L", len(key)), key, option])


class ReplicaSelector:
    def __init__(self):
        self._prf_seed = secrets.token_bytes(64)

    def assign(self, key, options):
        return min(options, key=lambda option: self._prf(encode_pair(key, option)))

    def _prf(self, data):
        return hmac.new(self._prf_seed, data, "sha256").digest()


selector = ReplicaSelector()
for dynamic_list in [
    ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4"],
    ["item2", "item3", "item4"],
    ["item0", "item1", "item2", "item3", "item4"],
    ["item0", "item1", "item3", "item4"],
]:
    print(dynamic_list)
    print(selector.assign("abc", dynamic_list), selector.assign("123", dynamic_list))
```

Sample outputs:

```
['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4']
item2 item2
['item2', 'item3', 'item4']
item2 item2
['item0', 'item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4']
item0 item2
['item0', 'item1', 'item3', 'item4']
item0 item0

['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4']
item1 item3
['item2', 'item3', 'item4']
item4 item3
['item0', 'item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4']
item1 item3
['item0', 'item1', 'item3', 'item4']
item1 item3

['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4']
item2 item3
['item2', 'item3', 'item4']
item2 item3
['item0', 'item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4']
item2 item3
['item0', 'item1', 'item3', 'item4']
item3 item3
```